# Typing a React component that clones its children to add extra props in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

Assuming you have following component that accepts one or more child JSX.Elements and passes extra callback to their props when they are rendered by using `React.cloneElement(child, { onCancel: () => {} }`.

**Component in question (excerpt):**

```
interface XComponentProps {
    onCancel: (index: number) => void;
}

class XComponent extends React.Component<XComponentProps> {
    render() {
        const { onCancel } = this.props;
        const children = typeof this.props.children === 'function' ?
            React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { onCancel: () => onCancel() }) :
            this.props.children.map((child, idx) => (
                React.cloneElement(child, { onCancel: () => onCancel(idx) })
            ));
        return <div>{children}</div>;
    }
}
```

**Component in question in action (excerpt):**

```
interface UserComponentProps { caption: string }
const UserComponent = (props: UserComponentProps) => (
    <button onClick={props.onClose}>{props.caption || "close"}</button>
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <XComponent onCancel={handleCancel}>
        <UserComponent />
        <UserComponent />
        <UserComponent />
    </XComponent>
);
```

Right now TSC is complaining that `UserComponent` does not have `onCancel` in its props' interface definition, which indeed does not. One easiest fix is to manually define `onCancel` to `UserComponentProps` interface.

However, I want to fix it without modifying child node's prop definition so that the component can accept arbitrary set of React elements. In such scenario, is there a way to define typings of returning elements that has extra implicit props passed at the `XComponent` (parent) level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible. There is no way to know statically what props UserComponent receives from parent XComponent in your ReactDOM.render context.

If you want a type safe solution, use children as functions:

Here is `XComponent` definition

```
interface XComponentProps {
    onCancel: (index: number) => void;
    childrenAsFunction: (props: { onCancel: (index: number) => void }) => JSX.Element;
}

class XComponent extends React.Component<XComponentProps> {
    render() {
        const { onCancel } = this.props;
        return <div>{childrenAsFunction({ onCancel })}</div>;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it to render your `UserComponent`s

```
<XComponent onCancel={handleCancel} childrenAsFunction={props => 
  <span>
    <UserComponent {...props} />
    <UserComponent {...props} />
  </span>
} />
```

This will work nicely, I use this pattern often with no hassle.
You can refactor XComponentProps to type the `childrenAsFunction` prop with the relevant part (the `onCancel` function here).

Comment: Thanks for the interesting solution! It makes sense to pass as function so that TSC can know relationship between the parent and children.

Answer (score 0):

You can use interface inheritance (see [Extending Interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)) and have UserComponentProps extend XComponentProps:

`interface UserComponentProps extends XComponentProps { caption: string }`

This will give UserComponentProps all the properties of XComponentProps in addition to its own properties.

If you don't want to require UserComponentProps to have all the properties of XComponentProps defined, you can also use Partial types (see [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)):

`interface UserComponentProps extends Partial<XComponentProps> { caption: string }`

This will give UserComponentProps all the properties of XComponentProps, but makes them optional.

Comment: Thanks @erikamjoh, that is my current workaround but I wanted to achieve it without modifying props of child components...

Answer (score 0):

You can pass children as a function, even in JSX. This way you will get proper typing all the way.
UserComponents props interface should extend ChildProps.

```
interface ChildProps {
    onCancel: (index: number) => void;
}

interface XComponentProps {
    onCancel: (index: number) => void;
    children: (props: ChildProps) => React.ReactElement<any>;
}

class XComponent extends React.Component<XComponentProps> {
    render() {
        const { onCancel } = this.props;
        return children({ onCancel })};
    }
}


<XComponent onCancel={handleCancel}>
    { props => <UserComponent {...props} /> } 
</XComponent>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Benoit B. said:

> It is not possible. There is no way to know statically what props
> UserComponent receives from parent XComponent in your ReactDOM.render
> context.

That said, there is an alternative to achieve that, using a High Order Component to wrap `UserComponent` (not modifying it, maybe renaming if it makes sense):

```
type RawUserComponentProps = Pick<XComponentProps, 'onCancel'> & {
  caption: string;
};

const RawUserComponent = (props: RawUserComponentProps) => {
  return <>...</>;
};

type UserComponentProps = Omit<RawUserComponentProps, 'onCancel'> & Pick<Partial<RawUserComponentProps>, 'onCancel'>;

export const UserComponent = (props: RawUserComponentProps) => {
  if (props.onCancel == null) {
    throw new Error('You must provide onCancel property');
  }
  return <RawUserComponent {...props} />;
};
```

You can also simplify that `Omit & Pick` to a `MakeOptional` type helper:

```
type MakeOptional<TObject, TKeys extends keyof TObject> = Omit<TObject, TKeys> & Pick<Partial<TObject>, TKeys>;

type UserComponentProps = MakeOptional<RawUserComponentProps, 'onCancel'>;
```

Answer (score -1):

### UPDATE: SOLUTION 2021

**Ran into this problem and have since figured out a neat workaround:**

Gonna use a Tabs component as an example but it's the same problem being solved (i.e. keeping TS happy when dynamically adding props to child components, from the parent).

---

##### `components/Tabs/Tab.tsx`

```js
// Props to be passed in via instantiation in JSX
export interface TabExternalProps {
  heading: string;
}

// Props to be passed in via React.Children.map in parent <Tabs /> component
interface TabInternalProps extends TabExternalProps {
  index: number;
  isActive: boolean;
  setActiveIndex(index: number): void;
}

export const Tab: React.FC<TabInternalProps> = ({
  index,
  isActive,
  setActiveIndex,
  heading,
  children
}) => {
  const className = `tab ${isActive && 'tab--active'}`;
  return (
    <div onClick={() => setActiveIndex(index)} {...className}>
      <strong>{heading}</strong>
      {isActive && children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

---

##### `components/Tabs/Tabs.tsx`

```js
import { Tab, TabExternalProps } from './Tab'; 

interface TabsProps = {
  defaultIndex?: number;
}
interface TabsComposition = {
  Tab: React.FC<TabExternalProps>;
}

const Tabs: React.FC<TabsProps> & TabsComposition = ({ children, defaultIndex = 0 }) => {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState<number>(defaultActiveIndex);
  const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
    if (!React.isValidElement(child)) return child;
    const JSXProps: TabExternalProps = child.props;
    const isActive = index === activeIndex;
    return (
      <Tab
        heading={JSXProps.heading}
        index={index}
        isActive={isActive}
        setActiveIndex={setActiveIndex}
      >
        {React.cloneElement(child)}
      </Tab>
    )
  })
  return <div className='tabs'>{childrenWithProps}</div>
}

Tabs.Tab = ({ children }) => <>{children}</>

export { Tabs }
```

---

##### `App.tsx`

```js
import { Tabs } from './components/Tabs/Tabs';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return(
    <Tabs defaultIndex={1}>
      <Tabs.Tab heading="Tab One">
        <p>Tab one content here...</p>
      </Tab>
      <Tabs.Tab heading="Tab Two">
        <p>Tab two content here...</p>
      </Tab>
    </Tabs>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This is different from the OP's question - you're not passing any props to children when you React.cloneElement(child).